# Microsoft assembly not copied to publish folder

Tags: msbuild

I have a `Visual Studio` solution where I manage `NuGet` packages globally with a `Packages.props` file. I have a filesystem publishprofile. Now I added a reference to the `NuGet` package `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`. When I publish the project, the `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll` is not in the `Bin` folder of the publish directory. Other `NuGet` packages work as expected, so I assume that this has to do with the fact that we have a System. assembly here.

I tried things like:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="bin\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and

```
<Target Name="DiagFile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="bin\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension) 
        </DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work when you rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best forum for this question; I would not have thought that you'd need to go to this length.  I presume you mean you are using PackageReference dependency packaging rather than packages.config?

I just created a blank ASPNET (Framework 4.7.2) app to test with. I added the `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` package and ran a publish to File System and the DLL was in the published `bin` directory.  This was using the `packages.config` model which is the default for this project type.

Converting to PackageReference mode, I can see the package has been referenced into the project in a pretty normal way...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource">
      <Version>6.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Publishing to File System still delivers the file to the bin directory. I haven't added any code to the project whatsoever at this point.